# Where can I get a switch for a 30A circuit?

Tags: electrical, switch

I would like to add a switch to a 30A plug, but I am having trouble finding one (they are all rated at 15a/20a).  Is there a reason you can't buy 30A switches or is it called something different?

To be more specific, I have a wall ac/heat unit that has a problem where it sometimes kicks on even when the switch is off.  Right now I just unplug it when not using it, but I don't like leaving a plug and socket there.

Comment: Another question on high-power switches: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/why-does-my-shower-switch-keep-burning-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get heavy duty switches at Grainger.

[image: Grainger 30A Switch]
[Grainger 30A Switch](http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/HUBBELL-WIRING-DEVICEKELLEMS-Industrial-Grade-5Z807?Pid=search)

Here is another at Grainger that is a bit less expensive than the switch above.

[image]
[Grainger 30A Switch](http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/LEVITON-Wall-Switch-2WER9)

Comment: Wrong type of switch for this application. ( did you even look at the price? )

Comment: I did not notice the link was for a double throw switch. I updated the link and image. The prices at Grainger are high, but they have a lot of customers. Go figure.

Comment: The switch in your link is a pretty standard double pole, not double throw. Double pole required for 120/240VAC. Typically, a 30 amp switch is going to be used on some high draw (motor) load. These switches are often make before break or other anti-arc/anti bounce contacts. Industrial capacity devices are not cheap, but a residential grade switch on a 30 amp motor load will weld up on the first try.

Comment: @shirlockhomes I'm not sure you can get a resi rated 30A switch, even commercial rated.  All I think they make now is Heavy Duty Industrial, like the ones listed above from Graingers.  Some imports might do it, but Hubbell, GE, Leviton, P&S and CWD just make the industrial.

Answer (score 8):

You may not find one at a box store or your local hardware store, because they are rare in residential settings.  However, if you go to an electrical supply store, they will have lots of them. Hubble, Square D, and others

Comment: I have bought 30 amp switches before, and got them at the electrical supply down in the "old commercial" part of town.  These guys sell to electricians, who more often something like that.  The consumer home box stores don't supply to that market as much.